# Select the result where multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to select the result with check the multiple columns.

```
 SELECT * FROM atricle WHERE  
    a.article_free_1 = 1 AND  
    a.article_free_2 = 1 AND 
    a.article_free_3 = 1 AND 
    a.article_free_4 = 1 AND 
    a.article_free_5 = 1 AND 
    a.article_free_6 = 1 AND 
    a.article_free_7 = 1 AND 
    a.article_free_8 = 1 AND 
    a.article_free_9 = 1 AND 
    a.article_free_10 = 1;
```

Here I want to simplify the query.Its going very long and I need to add 40+ columns in my query.

**How to simplify my query?**

Comment: Is the column value for which you are checking always the same (the number `1` in this case)?

Comment: I think, as I see it, you should normalize your table first

Comment: I believe you need to normalize your database, if those are your actual column names.

Comment: yes..i want the record which any one column having value "1"

Comment: i couldn't normalize.Because system previously done by using this method..

Comment: there could be couple of ways:
1. Try to use for loop in mysql queries directly
2. Try to create full query using for loop by PHP and then execute it.

Comment: If you **want the record which any one column having value "1"** than why `AND` ? You should use `OR`

Comment: If you can't normalise your database further then I wouldn't worry about the query being long. It may be long, but it is readable and easy to understand, which it won't be if you obfuscate it with loops.

Comment: @Chayan, if OR is what OP wants, IN is even better, i.e. 1 in (c1, c2, c3...).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this query very frequently then its better to create a calculated/computed column in the table. This will be like this:

```
(CASE WHEN article_free_1 = 1 
       AND article_free_2 = 1 AND ....THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

you can replace the query with :

```
SELECT * FROM atricle WHERE <computedColumn> = 1
```

it should simplify the query and give you optimized result eachtime you execute it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't simply comment yet so I'll post as an answer.
Your query is as optimal as it can get. A calculated field will just add overhead, getting in the way of the query optimizer trying to evaluate. Whatever you do, DON'T loop in sql, it was a horrendous addition way back trying to make people like SQL. Stick to standard queries. What you got is good.

-Edit I jus read what Jeemusu wrote. spot on.